# Forcing HTTPS in htaccess while rewriting a link

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

i'm trying to force HTTPS while rewriting a link in htaccess but had little luck...

Here's my original code..

```
RewriteRule ^Shopping-Cart/ shoppingCart/shoppingCart.php [L]
```

then i added code to force HTTPS so..

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^Shopping-Cart/ https://myserver.com/shoppingCart/shoppingCart.php [L]
```

but when loading `myserver.com/Shopping-Cart/` from a link i always end up to `https://myserver.com/shoppingCart/shoppingCart.php`

Can someone please drop me a hint ?

Thanks !

Comment: seems you cant use '!=' here. use '=off' instead.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because I believe you can't hide the fact that it's a secure link. i.e `https`. So even though Apache is set to use the `[L]` only it still does a Redirect because it's changing to the `https` protocol.

You need to change your htaccess to load the `https` first then handle the mod_rewrites.
Try,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^Shopping-Cart/? shoppingCart/shoppingCart.php [L]
```